# Add QIcon to QTableView cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget, qicon

I have already coded this for `QTableWidget`:

```
void ReadOnlyWindow::addReportIconToRow(const int rowIndex){
    QIcon icon;
    QSize sz(16, 16);

    icon.addPixmap(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_FileDialogEnd).pixmap(sz), QIcon::Normal);

    QTableWidgetItem *iconItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    iconItem->setText("report");
    iconItem->setIcon(icon);
    iconItem->setFlags(iconItem->flags() & (~Qt::ItemIsEditable));

    ui->homeWorksTable->setItem(rowIndex, REPORT_COLUMN_INDEX, icon);
}
```

`REPORT_COLUMN_INDEX` is `const int` from class and it has value `4`.

I am trying to found out how to rewrite code if table is `` QTableView`.

I was trying to use `setItemData()` and `setData()` but I think I used it in bad way because it didn't work.

P.S.: Now I want to do it for `QTableView` because its easy to load SQLite table there. This part works. I also added one more column. Now I need add to all rows of this column icon with text (how is in my code for `QTableWidget`). Function up there should be for one cell and will be implemented in loop.

Answer (score 0):

to add an icon to a tableWidget you set the item like specified [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) :

and when defining the `QTableWidgetItem`, use the constructor taking an Icon to be displayed.

here is a short example:

```
this->ui->myTable->setItem(row, col, new QTableWidgetItem(QIcon(":/resources_to_icon_.png"),"SomeText"));
```

in your code:

```
ui->homeWorksTable->setItem(rowIndex, REPORT_COLUMN_INDEX, QTableWidgetItem(icon,"some text");
```

Comment: Okey thank you byt my code for QTableWidget is working. I need to rewrite it to work it also for QTableView...Up there is my code for QTablWidget and its working.